# Rename menu links magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new to magento and I am interested in changing the menu from a magento website. I have installed the magento classic theme, I need to rename the 2 buttons from the main menu (Home and Products).

[image: menu]

I've tried modifying some files from `app/design/frontend/default/f002/template/page/html`, but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

I have the community version installed.

**Edit:** [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was really makes me astonished! However I installed this theme only for you and observed that it was by default menu.Ok NO problem just change the menu name here
open the file app\design\frontend\default\f002\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml and rename as you wish .See the image

[image]

And I want to tell you how to know that form which file this menu comes.It is very easy to detect in Magento. Just follow the few images!Please save the images at first or drag and drop each image into the new tab browser to see the actual image for more clear!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Go to the main page (frontend) page

[image]